# Como determinar o melhor MTU com Shell Script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, redes, ip, internet

O objetivo principal consiste em elaborar um algoritmo que faça uso da referida busca heurística, para minimizar a quantidade de iterações necessárias na determinação do MTU.

A ideia é utilizar um laço de repetição para executar o comando ping com diferentes quantidades de dados (incrementando ou decrementando essa quantidade) e sempre com a opção de não fragmentação ativa, de forma a induzir um erro de envio. A identificação do erro, que indica a necessidade de fragmentação, pode ser utilizada para determinar o valor do MTU para a tecnologia de enlace da rede.

Resumindo, queria saber como faço um script em Linux que sirva para ir testando diversos MTU com busca heurística e ir determinando qual o melhor para a rede que estou usando.

Por enquanto o código está assim do jeito q estava pensando, mas não sei se está correto:

```
aux1=`ifconfig | grep "inet " | awk '{print $3'\t'$4'\t'$5'\t'$6}'`
echo "${aux1}" 

echo "Determinacao do valor do MTU "
echo
i=0

for i in {1471..1473} do
        echo "ping com 1 pacote Nao Fragmentado com a QUANTIDADEdeDADOS:${i} 192.168.0.1"
        echo
        echo "ping -c 1 -s ${i} -M do 192.168.0.1"
    
        ping -c 1 -s ${i} -M do 192.168.0.1 | grep "local error" | awk '{print}'
        echo "maximo de bytes por pacote na rede: ${i}"

        #Aqui seria incrementado um if else para ir encontrando o melhor MTU para a rede
  done
```

Comment: Me parece que essa é uma pergunta para o [networkengineering.se], pois o problema em si é de rede (e MTU não é "melhor" ou "pior", se passar do correto paa a estrutura vai ter problemas de comunicação que vão alem de fragmentação. Só teste de ping não resolve isso, tem que entender a rede como um todo. Sobre o escopo, o script em si é "programado", mas não é o núcleo do problema. Ainda assim seria ampla e talvez um pouco opinativa, sem um critério ou problema mais definido para "qual é o melhor".

Comment: Como "dica", um dos algoritmos mais comuns na linha do dividir e conquistar, nessa linha: comece de um valor base, faça uma busca mais ampla e vá dividindo o passo pela metade para refinar. Exemplo bobo: "adivinhe um numero de 1 a 100" - "50" - "é maior" - "75" (aqui já dividimos o bloco restante no meio) - "é menor" - "63" - dividimos aproximadamente no meio novamente, de 50 a 75 - assim por diante (foi só pra ilustrar rapidinho)